# How to load a JSON in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following structure in a nodejs project:

```
-src
  --models
    ---product.json
  --main.js
```

I need to load the products.json inside the main. I am hav etested with import and require but none of them is working.

`let { product } = import('../models/product.json')`

I am getting the following error.message:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension \".json\" for /var/task/src/models/product.json",
```

This is my test model.json

```
{
  "model": "abc",
  "serial_number": "",
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: import * as product from "./models/product.json"

Comment: @kawadhiya21 I don't think that would help with the "Unknown file extension" error

Comment: the file you imported and actual file has different name. `product` vs `products`

Comment: Found a solution `let produc  = require('../models/product.json')` - without curly braces

Comment: @kawadhiya21 that was just a typo

Comment: I have edited my comment. Check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let product = require('../models/product.json')`